# Comparing database field with same name in different tables

Tags: php, sql, database

I haven't found an answer for this so far, so I figure you may be able to help me on this.

My database has 2 tables, both having a field called "email".

What I would like to do is to list all email addresses from both tables without showing the email twice. Any ideas, sample scripts, or something similar I could work from?

Thank you

D.

Comment: use a search engine to search for grouping, distinct and join. After that, create some code, and if it does not work the way you think it should, we can help you fix your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(SELECT email FROM table1) UNION DISTINCT (SELECT email FROM table2)
```

You'll need to replace your table and field names as appropriate

Comment: This will include the same email if other details of the row are different.

Comment: No, it will not.  DISTINCT or ALL operation on the columns in the result set, not the underlying table.

Comment: You're right. I forgot he was only selecting email. Oops.

Comment: Thank you, Jon Owens. This worked exactly as I needed.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. Just use a UNION command to join the results of two statements together.

```
SELECT email FROM table1
UNION
SELECT email FROM table2
```

Comment: I'm upvoting you because you recognize that the `distinct` is unnecessary with the `union`.

Comment: Not necessary, but it's always nice to show intent.

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email 
FROM
(
SELECT email FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT email FROM Table2
)
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complex.  Only the part between the parens is needed.